# What's the brix of a typical avocado?

Tags: food-science, nutrient-composition, avocados

What's the typical brix of a typical store-bought avocado? I mean the percentage of sugars, acids and such (I think it refers to all dissolved solids, but sugar gets the most attention). I can find the sugar content, but brix includes acids, minerals, and such, too. Does anyone have a refractometer and an avocado handy?

My hypothesis is that avocados have a very low brix. I'm not sure that they'd be easy to get juice out of, rather than an oily substance, though! I think juice is required to test the brix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic definition of Brix is grams sugar per 100 g solution. For an avocado, the FDA’s  nutrition data says that’s 8.5 °Bx.

The Brix scale is generally applied to solutions consisting mostly of sugar and water. That’s why it’s possible to use something like specific gravity or a refractometer to measure it. For solutions with other significant components, it’s not possible to use a refractometer or hydrometer to accurately measure Brix.